# SQL Server 2008 disk usage issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I heard SQL Server 2008 uses less disk space for the same amount of stuff (i.e. more compact format, and more disk space efficient, I mean storing MDF/LDF file) compared to previous version, like SQL Server 2000. Any document to prove that or describe that feature? I just need a high level learning, do not need too much detailed stuff.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the structure of a data page in SQL Server 2008 is pretty much the same as in SQL Server 2005.

There are a couple of new features though that can be used to improve space efficiency.

1. [Compression (Row and Page)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2007/11/12/types-of-data-compression-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)
2. [Sparse Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)

Comment: How about comparing to SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @George2 - I don't know off the top of my head. A good book on the subject is "SQL Server 2008 internals". I think again the basic structure of the data page itself hasn't changed that much but there were quite a few changes made to accommodate the new data types `varchar(max)` etc. and off row data. If you want to see how data is stored then check out [Internals Viewer](http://internalsviewer.codeplex.com/) on a development machine.